# How to aggregate date by some key on same slot in flink so that i can save network calls

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My flink job as of now does KeyBy on client id and thes uses window operator to accumulate data for 1 minute and then aggregates data. After aggregation we sink these accumulated data in hdfs files. Number of unique keys(client id) are more than 70 millions daily.

Issue is when we do keyBy it distributes data on cluster(my assumption) but i want data to be aggregated for 1 minute on same slot(or node) for incoming events.

NOTE : In sink we can have multiple data for same client for 1 minute window. I want to save network calls.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that doing a `stream.keyBy()` will cause network traffic when the data is partitioned/distributed (assuming you have parallelism > 1, of course). But the standard window operators require a keyed stream.

You could create a ProcessFunction that implements the `CheckpointedFunction` interface, and use that to maintain state in an unkeyed stream. But you'd still have to implement your own timers (standard Flink timers require a keyed stream), and save the time windows as part of the state.

You could write your own custom `RichFlatMapFunction`, and have an in-memory `Map<time window, Map<ip address, count>>` do to pre-keyed aggregations. You'd still need to follow this with a `keyBy()` and window operation to do the aggregation, but there would be much less network traffic.

I *think* it's OK that this is stateless. Though you'd likely need to make this an LRU cache, to avoid blowing memory. And you'd need to create your own timer to flush the windows.

But the golden rule is to measure first, the optimize. As in confirming that network traffic really is a problem, before performing helicopter stunts to try to reduce it.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe it's possible to use `MapState` in a non-keyed context. The only types of non-key-partitioned state are `ListState`, `UnionState`, and `BroadcastState`.

Comment: David is (of course) right. You also can't use ListState or ValueState with a non-keyed stream. And timers only work with a keyed stream. As such, I've edited my answer above to reflect an approach that does reduce (but not eliminate) network traffic.